# Fit data with any function and check when it reaches certain value

Tags: python, function, curve-fitting

Like title says. I wanna fit these points. Find an function and check at which x my function will hit 100.

```
    import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit



points = np.array([(3, 0), (7, 55), (14, 88)])
x = points[:,0]
y = points[:,1]
def func(x, p1,p2):
  return p1*np.log(x)+p2

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y,p0=(1.0,10.2))
print popt
p1 = popt[0]
p2 = popt[1]

curvex=np.linspace(15,85,1000)
fit = func(curvex, p1, p2)
plt.plot(x, y, 'yo', label='data')



plt.plot(curvex,fit,'r', linewidth=5)

plt.plot(x,y,'x',label = 'Xsaved')

plt.show()
```

[image]

1. How do I make the function go through points? (if its too much work its not necessary)
2. How do I get an x value at which y = 100?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you just want to print the x at which the function will hit 100? What exactly is the matplotlib tag doing here?

Comment: yeah I just want to print the x at which the function will hit 100. Will remove matplotlib :)

Comment: You need to have a finer mesh of x_new to get close to exact 100

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Oh, Sorry my bad. You have the polynomial so you can find the roots. Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can add a degree to your polynomial search. Try 4 instead of 3 for exemple, it will not go over 100

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial as P

points = np.array([(0, 0), (3, 0), (7, 55), (14, 88)])
x = points[:,0]
y = points[:,1]

y_fit = P.fit(x, y, 4)


x_new = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 50)

plt.plot(x,y,'o', x_new, y_fit(x_new))
plt.xlim([x[0]-1, x[-1] + 1 ])
plt.axhline(100)
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you really want to try to approximate when it will reach 100 with a 4th order:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial as P

points = np.array([(0, 0), (3, 0), (7, 55), (14, 88)])
# get x and y vectors
x = points[:,0]
y = points[:,1]

y_fit = P.fit(x, y, 4)
x_new = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)

plt.plot(x,y,'o', x_new, y_fit(x_new))
plt.axhline(100)
plt.show()
```

[image]

But nothing guarantee the truth of this trend as it can also be approximated with any other order or any other function

Comment: But this function will never reach 100?

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you are trying to do. Do you want the function to reach 100 after your max ?

Comment: Yes. Like a trendline. For my masters I need to write at which x(in theory) would my experiment reach 100%. PS :x is in time scale.

Comment: Depending of the degree of your polynomial function, you can have an infinity of solutions for f(x) = 100. Can't you just take a second order one and do the proportion?

Comment: Yeah thats the problem I can't fit very well, just started learning it today.

Comment: The problem is not in the fitting. The problem is that your problem can have an infinity of solutions. Your task is not well-posed in the mathematical meaning of the term.

Comment: Well there is some sort of trend isnt it? So you can calculate approximate value from it.

Comment: The trend can be approximated with infinite possibility so nothing guarantee the truth of your result. See my edit for an exemple

Comment: What if I put logarithmic trendline and now you see where approyimatelly will cross the 100 border. example : https://imgur.com/vtQsRoG

Comment: Check my exemple. The log trendline won't change anything as the problem will be the same i.e. no unique solution

Comment: Updated the code, maybe you can help with the code from here?

Answer (score 0):

There are two data points with a Y value of zero. After removing the single data point with the smallest X value (the left-most point on a scatterplot) I was able to easily fit the remaining data to the equation "y = a*ln(x+b)", which seems somewhat reasonable as you are extrapolating for the right-hand side of the scatterplot.

[image: plot2]

To find the X value where Y = 100 for this equation:

100 = a*ln(x+b)

I re-arrange as:

100/a = ln(x + b)

and take the natural exponent of each side:

exp(100/a) = x + b

Subtracting b from both sides gives me:

exp(100/a) - b = x

Using my fitted values for parameters a and b:

a =  3.5059370092556854E+01

b = -2.0057299645873785E+00

and since b is negative, this gives me:

exp(100/3.5059370092556854E+01) + 2.0057299645873785E+00 = x

which my calculator solves as my approximation for x at 100 as:

19.3334 = x

Comment: Hm I got 16.45 :) with exponential function from python.

Comment: Okay I updated the code up, if you could help me program it that would be swell :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d


points = np.array([(3, 0), (7, 55), (14, 88)])
x = points[:,0]
y = points[:,1]
def func(x, p1,p2):
  return p1*np.log(x)+p2

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y,p0=(1.0,10.2))
print popt
p1 = popt[0]
p2 = popt[1]

curvex=np.linspace(15,85,1000)
fit = func(curvex, p1, p2)
plt.plot(x, y, 'yo', label='data')

f = interp1d(fit, curvex, kind = 'cubic')
print f(100)
plt.plot(curvex,fit,'r', linewidth=1)

plt.plot(x,y,'x',label = 'Xsaved')

plt.show()
```

That answers my question. And the function crosses y = 100 at x = 16.54 value.